# Sum of all values except the first

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exception, sum

I have the following three tables:

> **Customers**:
>   Cust_ID,
>   Cust_Name
>
> **Products**:
>   Prod_ID,
>   Prod_Price
>
> **Orders**:
>   Order_ID,
>   Cust_ID,
>   Prod_ID,
>   Quantity,
>   Order_Date

How do I display each costumer and how much they spent excluding their very first purchase?

[A] - I can get the total by multiplying Products.Prod_Price and Orders.Quantity, then GROUP by Cust_ID

[B] - I also can get the first purchase by using TOP 1 on Order_Date for each customer.

But I couldnt figure out how to produce [A]-[B] in one query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Version of SQL-Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL-Server 2005, 2008 and 2008R2:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        c.Cust_ID, c.Cust_Name, 
        Amount = o.Quantity * p.Prod_Price,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID
                                ORDER BY o.Order_Date)
    FROM
        Customers AS c
      JOIN
        Orders AS o    ON o.Cust_ID = c.Cust_ID
      JOIN
        Products AS p  ON p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID 
  ) 
SELECT 
    Cust_ID, Cust_Name,
    AmountSpent = SUM(Amount)
FROM 
    cte 
WHERE 
    Rn >= 2
GROUP BY 
    Cust_ID, Cust_Name ;
```

For SQL-Server 2012, using the `FIRST_VALUE()` analytic function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.Cust_ID, c.Cust_Name,
    AmountSpent = SUM(o.Quantity * p.Prod_Price) 
                      OVER (PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID)
                - FIRST_VALUE(o.Quantity * p.Prod_Price) 
                      OVER (PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID
                            ORDER BY o.Order_Date)
FROM
    Customers AS c
  JOIN
    Orders AS o    ON o.Cust_ID = c.Cust_ID
  JOIN
    Products AS p  ON p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID ;
```

Another way (that works in 2012 only) using `OFFSET FETCH` and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT 
    c.Cust_ID, c.Cust_Name,
    AmountSpent = SUM(x.Quantity * x.Prod_Price) 
FROM
    Customers AS c
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT 
          o.Quantity, p.Prod_Price
      FROM 
          Orders AS o 
        JOIN
          Products AS p  ON p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID 
      WHERE
          o.Cust_ID = c.Cust_ID
      ORDER BY
          o.Order_Date
      OFFSET 
          1 ROW
      -- FETCH NEXT                        -- not needed,
      --     20000000000 ROWS ONLY         -- can be removed
    ) AS x 
GROUP BY 
    c.Cust_ID, c.Cust_Name ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42344/8)**

Note that the second solution returns also the customers with only one order (with the `Amount` as `0`) while the other two solutions do not return those customers.

Comment: I like the use of FIRST_VALUE. Do you know if similar could be achieved using OFFSET 1 simply sum without the first rather than doing the subtraction?

Comment: Thanks for posting solution 3. If you use an OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY you'll get customers with only one order for soln 3. Also, you can (should?) omit "FETCH NEXT 20000000000 ROWS ONLY"; the default is to fetch all rows after the offset. In the small sample the execution plan shows soln 3 to be take about 50% longer than 2.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of SQL? If 2012 you might be able to do something interesting with OFFSET 1, but I'd have to ponder much more how that works with grouping.

---

EDIT: Adding a 2012 specific solution inspired by @ypercube

I wanted to be able to use OFFSET 1 within the WINDOW to it al in one step, but the syntax I want isn't valid:

```
SUM(o.Quantity * p.Prod_Price) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID 
                                         ORDER BY o.Order_Date 
                                        OFFSET 1)
```

Instead I can specify the row boxing, but have to filter the result set to the correct set. The query plan is different from @ypercube's, but the both show 50% when run together. They each run twice as as fast as my original answer below.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.Cust_ID
        ,c.Cust_Name          
        ,SUM(o.Quantity * p.Prod_Price) OVER(PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID
                                                 ORDER BY o.Order_ID
                                                  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
                                                           AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AmountSpent
        ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Cust_ID ORDER BY o.Order_ID)
FROM Customers AS c
     INNER JOIN
     Orders AS o ON o.Cust_ID = c.Cust_ID
     INNER JOIN
     Products AS p ON p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID 
)
SELECT Cust_ID
      ,Cust_Name
      ,ISNULL(AmountSpent ,0) AmountSpent
  FROM cte WHERE rn=1
```

---

My more general solution is similar to peter.petrov's, but his didn't work "out of the box" on my sample data. That might be an issue with my sample data or not. Differences include use of CTE and a NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (Cust_ID INT, Cust_Name VARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE Products (Prod_ID INT, Prod_Price MONEY)
CREATE TABLE Orders (Order_ID INT, Cust_ID INT, Prod_ID INT, Quantity INT, Order_Date DATE)

INSERT INTO Customers SELECT 1 ,'Able' 
                UNION SELECT 2, 'Bob' 
                UNION SELECT 3, 'Charlie' 
INSERT INTO Products SELECT 1, 10.0
INSERT INTO Orders SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, GetDate()
             UNION SELECT 2, 1, 1, 1, GetDate()
             UNION SELECT 3, 1, 1, 1, GetDate()
             UNION SELECT 4, 2, 1, 1, GetDate()
             UNION SELECT 5, 2, 1, 1, GetDate()
             UNION SELECT 6, 3, 1, 1, GetDate()

;WITH CustomersFirstOrder AS (
  SELECT Cust_ID
        ,MIN(Order_ID) Order_ID 
    FROM Orders 
   GROUP BY Cust_ID
)
SELECT c.Cust_ID
      ,c.Cust_Name
      ,ISNULL(SUM(Quantity * Prod_Price),0) CustomerOrderTotalAfterInitialPurchase
  FROM Customers c
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT Cust_ID
               ,Quantity
               ,Prod_Price 
           FROM Orders o 
                INNER JOIN
                Products p ON o.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomersFirstOrder a WHERE a.Order_ID=o.Order_ID)
        ) b ON c.Cust_ID = b.Cust_ID

 GROUP BY c.Cust_ID
         ,c.Cust_Name

DROP TABLE Customers
DROP TABLE Products 
DROP TABLE Orders
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `MIN(Order_ID)` though but `MIN(Order_Date)`

Comment: @ypercube I saw that, but could not think of of why that would be preferable. In a real system it would depend on the rules with which the data is created. In a simple example it would be a wash.

Comment: `OFFSET` is not valid inside `OVER()`. Try to combine `OFFSET` with `CROSS APPLY`, I think that would work.

Comment: Failing to see how to do it with OFFSET and CROSS APPLY. Darn curious now though. Care to take a stab at in when you have a chance? If not, maybe I'll post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should do it.

```
SELECT  c1.cust_name ,
        c1.cust_id ,
        SUM(p1.Prod_Price)
FROM    orders o1
        JOIN products p1 ON o1.prod_id = p1.prod_id
        JOIN customers c1 ON o1.cust_id = c1.cust_id
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  o2.cust_id ,
                            MIN(o2.Order_Date) AS Order_Date
                    FROM    orders o2
                    GROUP BY o2.cust_id
                  ) t ON o1.cust_id = t.cust_id
                         AND o1.Order_Date = t.Order_Date
WHERE   t.Order_Date IS NULL
GROUP BY c1.cust_name ,
        c1.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to number orders by Customer and then you can have the amount for the first order and next orders with a CTE and ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
; WITH    NumberedOrders
      AS ( SELECT   Customers.Cust_Id ,
                    Customers.Cust_Name ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Customers.Cust_id ) AS Order_Number ,
                    Orders.Order_Date ,
                    Products.Prod_price * Orders.Quantity AS Amount
           FROM     Orders
                    INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.Cust_Id = Customers.Cust_Id
                    INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.Prod_Id = Products.Prod_Id
         )
SELECT  Cust_Id ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Number = 1 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS A_First_Order ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Number = 1 THEN 0
                 ELSE Amount
            END) AS B_Other_orders ,
        SUM(Amount) AS C_All_orders
FROM    NumberedOrders
GROUP BY Cust_Id
ORDER BY Cust_Id
```